# How to compare sub-sample mean with the sample mean?

Tags: statistical-significance, mean

I have a dataset with 983 rows and two columns: Rent and Postcode.

The mean Rent for the entire sample (983 rows) is 817.49.
The mean Rent for the N1 postcode (23 rows) is 887.02.

**The N1 data is a subset of my entire sample**; is it still possible to compare the means? How would I test whether Rent in N1 is significantly higher than average?

The statistical tests I have come across so far either rely on independent samples (I assume these are not independent as one is a subset of another), or dependent samples measured across time (which these are not).

Comment: You can compare them, iff you separate the sets beforehand, then N1 becomes a subgroup, and all the rest are your average..

Answer (score 1):

You need the average separately for the two groups (*N1* and *Not N1*), and from the information you posted the mean for *Not N1* can be calculated as
$$
   \frac{817.4 \cdot 983 - 887.02 \cdot 23}{983-23}.
$$
Then you can use the independent samples t-test (or some other test for independent samples).